# How to combine keypress & on click function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two functions:

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
   if (event.which == 13) {
   //code        
   }       
});

$('#login_submit').click(function () {        
   //code                    
});
```

The code which is being used in the functions are EXACTLY the same code, basically code dublication. So i was wondering if there is a way to combine these functions with an OR statement??

Comment: Why not just place that code in a separate function? And call the function...

Comment: i need the same but with an AND logic

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create your own callback and pass that to the event handlers.

```
var callback = function() {...};

$("input").keypress(function() {
    if (event.which == 13) callback();
});

$('#login_submit').click(callback);
```

Comment: I have used this solution and it works perfectly. Thanks David.

Answer (score 10):

Add a class to your HTML

```
<input class="myClass">
<div id="login_submit" class="myClass" ></div>
```

Now you can write:

```
$(".myClass").bind("keypress click", function(){});
```

Or do this:

```
$("input").add("#login_submit").bind("keypress click", function(){});
```

Be aware that clicking on the input will also trigger this.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        foospace.yourfunction();
    }       
});

$('#login_submit').click(function () {        
    foospace.yourfunction();                    
});

var foospace={}; 
foospace.yourfunction=function() { 
    alert("your code goes here!"); 
}
```

**Edit:**

The callback solution by @David is slightly more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I would chain the events like:

```
        var watchCurrentCursorPosition = function (){
            console.log("foo");
        }
        $("input").keypress(
            watchCurrentCursorPosition

        ).click(
            watchCurrentCursorPosition
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who still are looking for an answer to the @Sino's question.

> The code which is being used in the functions are EXACTLY the same code, basically code dublication. So i was wondering if there is a way to combine these functions with an OR statement??

JQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is the way to go.

> Description: Attach an event handler function **for one or more events** to the selected elements.

So your code could go like this:

```
$("input").on("click keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //code        
  }       
});
```