# How to combine keypress and onclick function Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two functions:

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
       //code        
    }       
});
$('#login_submit').click(function () {        
       //code                    
});
```

The code which is being used in the functions are EXACTLY the same code, basically code duplication. So i was wondering if there is a way to combine these functions with an AND statement?? There is an question on Stack but it aks for an OR logic. If you want the OR solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674456/how-to-combine-keypress-on-click-function-in-javascript)

EDIT: I am trying to make somthing like an explorer. Now I want to hold "shift" and click on an "input" to mark them all. So i need the "onclick" on my input element to be true AND my keydown to be true.

Comment: Just put the bulk of the code in a function and call that function - keeping the handlers separate will make it easier to read.

Comment: Are you saying that you want both events at the same time?

Comment: link in your question is the best answer

Comment: What do you even mean by “combining with an AND” here ...? Do you want the handler function to only be executed if the user presses enter and clicks the submit button at the same time …? (That sounds like a nice way to eff up a UI, if you ask me.) If that’s not it, but just just want to have the same function handle both events, occurring independent of each other - well then what are you asking, that’s be answered in the other question already ...?

Comment: How is **this question** any different from the question you've linked in your question?   Pressing enter *and* clicking *at the same time* makes no sense.

Comment: Hey it is not an duplicate from the linked question. The different is aks i wrote i should be AND!

Comment: @Erdnuss can you explain what "AND" events actually means in real terms please?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying (edit to question).  You can use the event object (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to see which keys are pressed.  You won't be able to do this with `keypress`, but you could with `keydown`/`keyup`: Looks like this is what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43141764/2181514

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need. Would you @freedomn-m post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

After your edit, I believe what you are looking for is something like the following.

```
var shift_hold = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 16) {
        shift_hold = true;
    }
})

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 16) {
        shift_hold = false();
    }
})

$('input').click(function() {
    if(shift_hold) {
        //your code here
    }
})
```

Comment: This doesn't check the keypress keycode.

Comment: This question answers the question specified by the title exactly. I don't see a reason for the downvote. The OP has clearly demonstrated knowledge of targeting and key events, this is all the OP needs to complete his task as asked by the question.

Comment: Without additional information, it's not clear *what* the OP wants as they've already provided a link to a "valid" answer (ie the same as this answer!) within the question itself.

Comment: Not what I asked for. But anyway thank :)

Comment: @Erdnuss I edited my answer after your clarification

Answer (score 1):

> I want to hold "shift" and click on an "input" to mark them all. So I need the "onclick" on my input element to be true AND my keydown to be true.

Within the `click` event, you can check if a key is also pressed down (click *and* key-is-down).

You can use the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object) to see which keys are pressed.  shift/control/alt have their own explicit properties.

Example:

```js
$("input").click(function() {
  console.log(event.shiftKey)
  if (event.shiftKey) {
    $(this).addClass("selected")
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("selected")
  }
  // could use .toggleClass("selected", event.shiftKey) here,
  // shown expanded for clarity
});
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Shift-click input to select, click to unselect
<input type='text'>
<input type='text'>
```